# What can I do to follow/replicate a home exercise routine at the gym?

Tags: workout-routines, p90x

Several years ago, I was following along P90X and seeing some nice progress up until about 2/3rds through my first round when I sprained my ankle playing Ultimate. Long story short, life happened, and I haven't really actively worked out since. Fast forward to today, I'm in a very different situation. I have P90X-3 on-hand, but I lack the space at my current home to work out in (which includes my living room - this is a much smaller house than my previous one).

My wife is already a member at a local gym which does offer some perks. However, access to personal trainers costs additional money that I'm not really interested in spending. Since I like the concept of having an exercise routine to follow, I was thinking of simply following P90X-3 at the gym, but mastering the exercises are only possible after many repetitions and following along with them is certainly helpful in order to keep pace and compare my form to ensure I'm doing things properly. What can I do to keep going with P90X-3 but utilizing the available resources at my local gym?

Comment: Is the problem that P90x is video based?

Comment: @fordprefect: That's certainly an important part of it. I'm essentially replacing a personal trainer, who would otherwise help ensure my form stays correct, with a video. When I first did P90X, I was still making small form corrections well into the second and even third month of the routine.

Comment: If you like P90x then you can see if they have a way they can download the videos on your phone. Otherwise apps like NTC, freeletics, or under armour achieve the same purpose

Comment: @fordprefect: How do you use your phone when you're lifting free weights or doing yoga?

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments if p90x supports downloading the videos or watching them on youtube those are certainly options. Most gyms have open space for calisthenics or stretching that you can use and bluetooth headphones work well to listen without bothering others.

If your goal is a general electronic substitute to an expensive personal trainer I tend to recommend several mobile apps that help you track pace and progress that give certain exercises, reps, and depending on the app resistance levels. I have personally used Nike Training Club and Freeletics but I know people who have used the Under Armour and Kayla apps to great effect.

Regarding using your phone at the gym, I typically put it on the equipment I am using, on the floor nearby me, or depending on the exercise in my pocket. Many people listen to music on their phones as it is at the gym so this is unlikely to raise eyebrows.

Comment: Yeah, forgetting about p90x's effectiveness, I'd just toss an ipad / phone leaned up on the ground and have at it.

Comment: @EricKaufman: Heh, that's a dangerous lead-in to a shopping question for someone like me who needs a routine that holds my hand but doesn't want to spend a couple hundred a month on personal trainers.